# Finding a Pair Contract on PancakeSwap

Tags: solidity, pancakeswap, binance-smart-chain

I was explained that to find the pair contract on PancakeSwap, all that's needed to be done is go to the Factory contract of Pancakeswap on **bscscan** ( `0xcA143Ce32Fe78f1f7019d7d551a6402fC5350c73` ), find the `getPair()` function in the read section of the contract, and insert the addresses of each of the cryptocurrencies in the pair.

I did this for WBNB and BUSD:

- **WBNB contract address:**

  ```
  0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c
  ```
- **BUSD contract address:**

  ```
  0xe9e7cea3dedca5984780bafc599bd69add087d56
  ```

and I got the following contract:

- **Obtained pair contract address from the `getPair()` function on the Pancake Factory contract:**

  ```
  0x58F876857a02D6762E0101bb5C46A8c1ED44Dc16
  ```

  - [Source](https://bscscan.com/address/0x58F876857a02D6762E0101bb5C46A8c1ED44Dc16)

So far so good. The obtained contract shows about 244 million dollars worth of WBNB and about the same in BUSD inside it's liquidity pool. **However!!...** I randomly online found that there is another pair contract on PancakeSwap for the same pair of cryptocurrencies (**WBNB/BUSD**):

- [0x1b96b92314c44b159149f7e0303511fb2fc4774f](https://bscscan.com/address/0x1b96b92314c44b159149f7e0303511fb2fc4774f)

And now I'm entirely confused. I previously thought that only one pair can exist on PancakeSwap for 2 cryptocurrencies, but apparently that isn't accurate.

**My Question:**

Doesn't PancakeSwap only allow one contract per a specific pair of crypocurrencies? **In the case that it doesn't**, which pair is `getPair()` in the PancakeSwap Factory deciding to give you if there is more than one possible answer? **In the case that only one pair can exist**, then how was I able to find two contracts for this pair?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you're looking at the different PancakeSwap contracts versions. Example:

**PancakeRouter V1** - 0x05ff2b0db69458a0750badebc4f9e13add608c7f

**PancakeFactory V1** - 0xbcfccbde45ce874adcb698cc183debcf17952812

**PancakeRouter V2** - 0x10ed43c718714eb63d5aa57b78b54704e256024e

**PancakeFactory V2** - 0xca143ce32fe78f1f7019d7d551a6402fc5350c73

And so the contract *0x58F876857a02D6762E0101bb5C46A8c1ED44Dc16* is the WBNB/BUSD pair living inside the **PankcakeRouter V2** and the contract *0x1b96b92314c44b159149f7e0303511fb2fc4774f* is the WBNB/BUSD pair living inside the **PankcakeRouter V1**. They're completely different pairs with different liquidity ( not so different, because of arbitrage traders ). Every version is somehow better than the previous, currently I just saw that **V1** is not supported anymore ( the contract might still be live, but PancakeSwap removed it from their interface ).

And as we know PancakeSwap is a fork of UniSwap and UniSwap presented lately **V3** with another set of good features. I'm not sure if PancakeSwap will follow **V3**.

Comment: Your answer was exactly what I was looking for, thank you